# Ansible for Openshift Deployment

Tags: ansible, openshift

I want to deploy the pods on Openshift using Ansible Playbook.

For this, i have written the following play :

```
    - name: Create Deployment Config for the usecase
      with_dict: "{{ apps }}"
      openshift_v1_deployment_config:
         name: "{{ item.key }}"
         namespace: "{{ usecaseId }}"
         labels: 
           app: "{{ item.key }}"
           service: "{{ item.key }}"
         replicas: 1 
         selector: 
           app: "{{ item.key }}"
           service: "{{ item.key }}"
         spec_template_metadata_labels:
          app: "{{ item.key }}"
          service: "{{ item.key }}"
         containers: 
          - env:
             image: "{{ openshift_registry_svc_url }}/{{ usecaseId }}/{{ item.key }}"
             name: "{{ item.key }}"
             ports:
               - container_port: 8080
                 protocol: TCP
```

Anyone having idea how can i get the ip-address of the deployed pod using ansible itself.TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally I found it .
This could be done using following kubernetes module provided by ansible : k8s

e.g. :

```
- name: Fetch all pods which are running
  set_fact:
     deployments_pod: "{{ lookup('k8s', kind='Pod', namespace=test) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Shagun , I do not think that you would be able to get the IP address of the pods outside the cluster as the IP are managed by the openshift SAN the outside world can connect to pods are by routes, port forwarding ,Manually assign an external IP to a service
Hope this url helps with the methods to connect to pods https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/expose_service/index.html